# Creating a Dynamic on Demand Input field

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, semantic-ui

I am new to React and doing a personal project to help with some organization in my life.

I have a field where I need to be able to add multiple names some times. I think I am close...I can't get the fields to appear but they act like they are all the same field, like they are bound together

[Here is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iit50.png)

NameInput.jsx (component)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Label } from "semantic-ui-react";

const NameInput = ({
  input,
  width,
  type,
  placeholder,
  meta: { touched, error }
}) => {
  let [inputs, setInputs] = useState([""]);

  return (
    <div className="nameField">
      <Form.Field error={touched && !!error} width={width}>
        {inputs.map((value, i) => (
          <div>
            <label>Name {i + 1}</label>
            <input {...input} placeholder={placeholder} type={type} />{" "}
            {touched && error && (
              <Label basic color="red">
                {error}
              </Label>
            )}
            {e =>
              setInputs(
                inputs.map((value, j) => {
                  if (i === j) value = e.target.value;
                  return value;
                })
              )
            }
          </div>
        ))}
      </Form.Field>
      <button
        className="ui compact button"
        onClick={() => setInputs(inputs.concat(""))}
      >
        Add Additional Seller
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NameInput;
```

And this is how I call the component. This stores to my firebase as nameField

```
  <label>Name Field</label>
  <Field
    name="nameField"
    type="text"
    component={NameInput}
    placeholder="Enter Full Name"
  />
```

Ideally, I'd want it to save has nameField, namefield2, nameField3 but I believe I can get that part solved on my own if I could just get my component to play nice.

Comment: Can you please update the snippet and add the import for `Field` component?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you ever get a warning that a key should be provided for list items?

You should assign a unique key for each input div.